# Getting username from click to insert into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a @mention script and I'm stuck on one little issue.

So each user selects a user then clicks that user and it appends the username into the newmsg div and then you can write some text also, like a status you would find on twitter or facebook. Like so. I'm also currently using the old jquery 'live' also but will be changing that shortly.

```
$(".addname").live("click",function() 
{
var username=$(this).attr('title');
var old=$("#newmsg").html();
var contents=old.replace(word,""); 
$("#newmsg").html(contents);
var E="<a class='red' contenteditable='false' href='/profile.php?username="+username+"'>"+username+"</a>";
$("#newmsg").append(E);
$("#display").hide();
$("#newmsg").focus();
```

I would like to then somehow get that username to be able to add it to my insert so I can keep it as a link when it inserts the ajax post.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#myforms").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var content = $(this).children("#toid").val();
                var newmsg= $(this).children('#newmsg').text();
                var USERNAME HERE= ??;
                var privacy = $("#privacy").val();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg, privacy: privacy, USERNAME HERE },
```

And here is the link I'm using in insert.php to convert the @username to a link. Please note below my $_POSTvariables are not sanitized and are vulnerable to SQL injection. But that will be rectified.

```
$_POST['newmsg']=str_replace('@','<a href="profile.php?username='.$_POST['username'].'">'.$_POST['username'].'</a>',$_POST['newmsg']);
```

I tried using

```
var username = $(this).children(".addname").val();
```

but it stated that it was undefined.

Here is the html when user checks for available users and clicks them to be selected.

```
<div class="display_box "align="left">
<? echo "<img class='image' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$id.".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" >"; ?>
<a href="#" class='addname' title='<?php echo $username; ?>'><?php echo $fname." ".$lname; ?></a>
</div>
</br>
```

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Html of selected user link provided as requested.

Comment: addname is a link class of which I've now provided at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Link (`a href`) , so use

```
var username = $(".addname").attr("href");
```

instead of

```
var username = $(this).children(".addname").val();
```